# How to remove (duplicate) X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0

Tags: jsf-2, http-headers, glassfish-3

In my instance, I have
Glassfish 3.1.1 / Mojarra 2.1.3

I could remove the X-Powered-By in Glassfish Admin Console in the Network listener (so it doesn't show the long text:

```
Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Java/Sun Microsystems Inc./1.6)
```

but it still shows (yes, twice):

```
X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
```

I am using Jersey and JAXB to expose some web-services and have some servlets deployed using the @WebServlet Annotation but I don't think they add anything.

It is not generated by mod_jk or Apache because I get those headers even when connecting to the application port directly (localhost:8080)

Is there typical modules that would do that in Glassfish? How can I remove these headers?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's been set by Mojarra. You can disable it by setting the context parameter `com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader` to `false` in webapp's `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, that it sends the value twice is a mystery to me. This is not the default behaviour and technically impossible (as it would indicate the `ExternalContextImpl` being constructed twice on the same response). Perhaps `mod_jk` is doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't look very well documented (or I am a very bad "Googler"). Even with your solution, I can find only a single hit in Google that mentions that (and I used sendPoweredByHeader in search keywords :S )
Also, with this config both lines are removed... I am not using mod_jk when testing on my machine (I will edit the post for clarification)

Comment: If you're using glassfish, you'll also need to specifically tell glassfish to not include this in the header.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/chameleon_glassfish_x_powered_by for instructions.