# Override X-Powered-By HTTP Header

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, filter

As per some security requirement have to set the X-Powered-By header to an empty String. I have been trying to set the header in a filter but when I look at the headers in Firebug I see that the custom header value set by my filter is appended by JSF/ 1.2.

The Filter is the first one in the request chain and implicitly the last one in the response chain.
Below is the sample code that i have written in the doFilter method.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
    // App specific logic...
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By","");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Am using Tomcat 6. As my filter is the last one in the response chain, is tomcat setting this header again after the control goes back to the tomcat connector ?

How do I override this value to my custom value ?

Comment: You know, security by obscurity doesn't really work.

Comment: Yes am aware, this security requirement is on top of other already implemented robust mechanisms. If this can demotivate at least one illegitimate user from doing something, i think I would break-even :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the response header before the rest of the application has had time to process the response. You should set it after the `doFilter` call

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
// before filters and servlets
chain.doFilter(request, response);
// after filters and servlets
httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By","");
```

Also, make sure the response [isn't committed before setting the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030152/srtservletres-w-warning-cannot-set-header-response-already-committed).  You might have to change what your other servlets are doing or wrap the `HttpServletResponse`.

If the header is being added by the Jasper JSP engine, you can check to see if it's [configured that way](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html). Your Jasper servlet in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` might have the `init-param` `xpoweredBy` set to `true`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis : Thanks Setting the header after chaining does not seem to set the custom value. Setting it before does set it but the value "JSF /1.2" gets appended to it. The xpoweredBy init-param was by default set to false. Any other pointers ?

Comment: @Anugoonj Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846090/how-to-remove-duplicate-x-powered-by-jsf-2-0

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question on Stackoverflow here [JSF, override HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803851/jsf-override-http-headers)

In short: you need to write a PhaseListener. A filter seems to be called before the JSF servlet so your header will be overwritten when you're trying to overwrite the response header.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove disable the X Powered By header in Wildfly as well as the Weblogic server.

*For Wildfly Server=>*

Navigate to the path Configuration⇒Subsystem⇒Web=>Settings⇒Servlet Container⇒default=>JSP

We can see that the X Powered By header configuration,the same we can enable or disable.

[Wildfly X Powered By header configuration] https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs4TT.png

*For Weblogic Server=>*

Navigate to the path Home=>Summary of Domain Partitions=>Summary of Deployments=>Summary of Domain Partitions=>Summary of partition Work managers=>base_domain=>Configurations=>Web Applications

We can see that the X Powered By header configuration,the same we can enable with the values or disable.

[Weblogic X Powered By header configuration] https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFvrM.png